# Unable to deploy the application

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ubuntu, tomcat, mariadb

i am trying to deploy the application using Tomcat with the help of docker for deployment and `mariaDB` as database. 
The respective generated `war` file is getting deployed but when i try to access other pages(other than the base url/landing page) its showing the following error:

```
web-app_1  | 07:20:00.324 [http-apr-8080-exec-3] INFO com.company.controller.MainController - in Main controller
web-app_1  | 07:20:00.806 [http-apr-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator - Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
web-app_1  | 07:20:00.952 [http-apr-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [n/a]
web-app_1  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=833)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
web-app_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:156)
web-app_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:118)
web-app_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:92)
web-app_1  |    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:108)
web-app_1  |    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
web-app_1  |    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
web-app_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
web-app_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
web-app_1  |    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
```

and `hibernate.properties` file contains:

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams_dbnew
jdbc.username = username

jdbc.password = password
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = none
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

Although am pointing to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/` but in tomcat logs its showing error as `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=833)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)`

and database is running on same `3306` port

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      121        410570      51950/mysqld
```

can anyone tell me where and which part am doing wrong?

and `docker-compose` file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
       - 8080:8080
    network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: Have a look here.. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/422

Comment: localhost change it with 127.0.0.1 and try again

Comment: nothing changes. Changes `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` still the same error. Why it is showing `833` in logs. Where i am pointing it to `3306`?

Comment: clean webapps, temp and work directory and try again. it should not be solution but just try it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the port 833, try searching the number "833" in your tomcat home directory

```
cd /TOMCAT_HOME_DIRECTORY/
grep -rli 833 .
```

may be one of the file overriding the port number.

Answer (score 0):

As seeing your logs, it seems there is another database service is configured on 833 port and it is overridden while running tomcat with database app.
Make sure any database you didn't configured with this port. stop all database service then also stop closed this port via following this command:
netstat -ap | grep :
it search the process running on this port
kill -9 
kill that process id running on this port no.